# Show a list of items on a page with a delete button near every item

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page in which I show a list of items that I receive after an ajax call. I populate a table with them.
I can show their names followed by a button pretty simple.

```
            $.ajax ({
                type: "GET",
                url: "show_products.php",
                data: {},
                success: function(result) {
                    result = $.parseJSON(result);
                    console.log(result);

                    $.each(result, function(i, r) {
                        $("#products").append($('<tr>')
                            .append($('<td>').append(r.Name))
                            .append($('<td>').append('<input name = "btn_delete" type = "submit" value = "delete">'))
                            );
                    });
                },
                error: function(r) {
                    console.log(r);
                }
            });
```

But the question is, how can I make another ajax call when that button is pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("input[type=submit][value='delete']").click(function() {
//do something here
alert("its working");
});
```

trigger a click event on the submit button.

Comment: +1, a shorthand of this solution is to simply use chainability: `...append('<input name = "btn_delete" type = "submit" value ="delete">').click(function() {});`

Comment: and I can easily do a post from that function with whatever parameters I want. Nice. I did something not so elegant to refresh the list after a delete: a second ajax call inide the click handler.